# How to see the results of Apple TV's network tests?

Tags: appletv

I can run the network test inside the settings menu. But at the end I only see "Network test successfully complete".

[image]

I don't see what speeds the Apple TV 3 is actually getting at that spot in the house. It's a pretty dumb thing thing to conduct the test and not have even the basic stuff (like xyz Mbps) reported back!

Are those results posted somewhere else on the Apple ID? Or can I pull them off the Apple TV somehow? Note that the Apple TV is NOT jailbroken and is running the latest OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: No

The network test is testing whether the AppleTV is connected to a network.  That's all it is doing.

- AppleTV connected to network = success
- AppleTV not connected to network = failed

Comment: If I recall correctly, it does all the above tests by attempting connection to the iTunes Store.

Comment: So if I was on a dialup connection it would still show it as "Pass" ?! There has to be (or should be!) more fidelity to the test than just connectivity considering the #1 purpose of the Apple TV is to stream media (mostly HD that too). Interesting ...